# How can I write my query to pull up a result like this ? Last names, sex count

Tags: mysql, sql, ccl

VIEW DESIRED RESULT HERE

[image]

So far what I have is 
this result here based on the query below

[image]

...and that is not very close to what I need

```
SELECT
P.NAME_LAST,    
COUNT(P.NAME_LAST),    
P_SEX_DISP = UAR_GET_CODE_DISPLAY(P.SEX_CD),    
COUNT(P.SEX_CD)
FROM
    PERSON P
GROUP BY
P.NAME_LAST    
ORDER BY P.NAME_LAST ASC
```

Comment: Please post your table structure. For example the fields.

Comment: May you link me to an example of what that may look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation something like this:

```
select name_last,
    sum(sex_cd = 'male'),
    sum(sex_cd = 'female'),
    sum(sex_cd not in ('male','female')),
    count(*)
from person
group by name_last
order by name_last asc
```